# Meaning of ‘yet’ and ‘ever’ in ‘yet the waters ever change, flowing like time, the path is yours to climb’

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw there are a lot of meanings of yet. For example, looking at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet) I found these possible meanings:

- Besides, in addition
- Even
- on top of everything else, no less
- so far
- so soon
- still
- eventually
- however, nevertheless

Similar with [ever](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ever): always, in any time, in any way, ...

But then while watching the lyrics of [*Lost in Thoughts All Alone*](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_in_Thoughts_All_Alone) from the game Fire Emblem Fates, I couldn't decide which of those would fit better:

> You are the ocean's gray waves, destined to seek
> life beyond the shore just out of reach.
> **Yet** the waters **ever** change, flowing like time
> the path is yours to climb.

For me, I would think as ‘**even (if)** the waters **in any way** change’, but not really sure. Another possibility would be ‘**however** the waters **always** change’. What is your opinion? Is definitely one specific meaning of *yet* and *ever* that is involved into that sentence or the authors left on purpose the ambiguity because it's a song?

Comment: Punctuation of that seems a bit odd, so it's hard to parse. (Are these lyrics from a random website, rather than something properly published and edited?) Should probably have a semicolon or something after time. But at the start of a sentence it normally has a concessive quality, meaning still or however.

Comment: The sense as cited is ***yet = still, but, nevertheless,...***

Comment: @StuartF The song is of a game, I took the lyrics from the fandom website. I updated the link

Comment: asimismo is yet.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough, so I updated the question with the two meanings I thought based on the first comments because actually I'm not sure I'm understanding the whole sentence

Comment: Asimismo las aguas siempre cambian.

Comment: "ever change" would more usually be something like "constantly change". Agree with others about "yet". "However" would probably be my perferred alternative, but any of the others would do. Lyrics like this are often open to interpretation.

Comment: I would have chosen "always", but keep in mind that poetry is in general a poor vehicle for learning language, there are often far more considerations going into word choice than any of the usual meanings ascribed to them.

Comment: The lyric is somewhat opaque and its logical flow isn't clear. Most likely **yet** would mean "nevertheless" or "however" but that line is an apparent *non sequitur*, unless the meaning is that the person will somehow be able to climb after the waters change in some way, and they are **always** changing.  At any rate, it's elliptical and there will be no definite answer here.

Comment: There is no ambiguity for me. The first two lines state the mission and limitations. The next two lines counter that with the idea that all things change, and you must try anyway.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Unfortunately, poetry is my unique motivation to study English

Comment: It's ambiguous unless you impose a lot of assumptions. For one thing it's not clear if the waters or the path are "flowing like time".